# Wide columns pushing content off XAML Grid

Tags: xaml, layout, grid, windows-runtime

I'd like to show a Grid with three columns, where each column fills the available space but not so that they push subsequent columns off the end of the grid. Each column needs to have at least some of its content (defined by MinWidth) visible.

This is what I'm after:

```
___________________________________________
|                      |         |        |
|very-wide-first-col...|second...|third...|
|______________________|_________|________|
```

This is what I get:

```
___________________________________________
|                           |             |
|very-wide-first-column-text|second-column|-text|third-column-text
|___________________________|_____________|
```

Here's my code:

```
<Grid>
  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
  <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="very-wide-first-column-text" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"/>
  <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="second-column-text" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"/>
  <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="third-column-text" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"/>
</Grid>
```

No combination of MinWidth and MaxWidth seems to achieve the desired layout - it seems they don't work with Auto and proportional sizing isn't what I want. I also tried using a DockPanel but that didn't help.

Comment: Remove the `Width="Auto"` in the first `ColumnDefinition`. Is the result what you are looking for?

Comment: No, because then if the second column gets too wide, it pushes the first column's content off the left of the grid.

Comment: If this is the case, that means the total width of all three goes over the width of the grid. How do you expect to show them?

Comment: I want them to get truncated so the grid shows at least the width specified by each column's (or its content's) MinWidth.

Answer (score 0):

Use stars.

Width="2*" for the first column
Width="1*" for the other two.

This means that the total width available is divided evenly between the total of the numbers (in this example 4 - with the first column being 2/4 and the others each being 1/4 of the available width).

The total width is determined by whatever container the columns are in (the grid).

Comment: This way, the first column will always take half the available space, and the others 1/4, whereas I want it to be dynamic based on the width of each column's text (but using Auto just pushes everything off the end).

Looks like I'm going to have to create a custom panel.

Comment: I don't think there is a simple way to do what you want because, logically, how can the XAML determine how wide to make each column if they all have 'too much' or 'too little' content? Personally I would look at wrapping the text and fixing the column widths, but it depends if that's suitable in your specific project.

Comment: It ocurred to me that you might be able to use multiple columns per text column - e.g. have each text block span 2 or 3 columns, set the first of these columns to a fixed width (your minimum for the text), then let the other 1 or 2 columns change automatically as needed. This might work with a bit of experimentation.